# How can you share bundles in an angular 5 application?

Tags: angular-cli

#### Versions

```
Angular CLI: 1.6.0
Node: 7.9.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 5.1.2

... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

@angular/cdk: 5.0.2
@angular/cli: 1.6.0
@angular/material: 5.0.2
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.0.36
@angular-devkit/core: 0.0.22
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.0.42
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.9.0
@schematics/angular: 0.1.11
@schematics/schematics: 0.0.11
typescript: 2.4.2
webpack: 3.10.0
```

#### Repro steps

It doesn't seem to be possible to share a polyfills or style sheet bundles between applications.

The angular cli json file accepts properties

```
"main": "main.ts",
"polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
```

But that means that the polyfills bundle is built from the typescript file in the project.

#### Observed behavior

In the build command output the file names of the bundles loaded via script tags in the index.html are specific to the build:

```
Date: 2018-01-02T14:36:14.208Z
Hash: fd6ba1fc91245625191d
Time: 200577ms
chunk {0} main.73d822577495d0d76c3f.bundle.js, main.566ea3335f891f0ca934.bundle.css (main) 933 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {1} polyfills.e63bc529865281215d4c.bundle.js (polyfills) 389 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {2} styles.566ea3335f891f0ca934.bundle.css (styles) 18.2 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {3} inline.f3a6256283c314c7e1cc.bundle.js (inline) 1.45 kB [entry] [rendered]
```

#### Desired behavior

That a 'parent' project build could build the polyfills and/or css bundles and then 'child' projects could reference them?

The different child projects would have independent build lifecycles and be self-contained, a shared polyfills/css would improve page load times when navigating between applications.

#### Mention any other details that might be useful (optional)

I looked at

http://www.velocitypartners.net/blog/2017/09/26/webpack-splitt-app-vendor-polyfill-builds/

but this seems to be angular 4 specific (??) and requires messing with the package.json .

Comment: I have also seen https://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/angular-modules-barrels-and-aot/ which suggests using ng eject to convert a cli project to a webpack project but using --aot / --prod / --build-optimizer with ng eject has no effect on the build output .It isn't clear to me how you build an angular 5 project via webpack for production?

Comment: "share" is a broad term. Do you want the end projects to consume in the browser or you want to utilize this in the target project as in https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1692 ?

Comment: Share ultimately in the browser. Currently our projects do not have shareable components (though they may do in the future). The question arose primarily from looking at the performance of the app and specifically download times and sizes of bundles. The polyfills bundle is large (~.5 MB) and if it is common between separate angular 5 applications then it would be good to only download and parse it once.

Comment: You can take a look at https://github.com/yogeshgadge/ngx-library-builder 
 (*disclosure - I am the author) which is based on https://github.com/filipesilva/angular-quickstart-lib created by the member of angular-cli itself. They all essentially build artifacts that can be consumed in different forms.

Comment: You may also want to understand the basic problem that you have run into at a broader level at the discussion thread https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6510

Comment: I've come to the conclusion that the simplest (though not cleanest) approach here will be to have a a bit of shell scripting to  replace the location of any common bundles (such as polyfills or vendor) in index.html with absolute URLs served from a location that shares the same domain. This will be done within the build script after the ng build --prod --build-optimizer step.