# Angular CLI: Multiple Common chunks

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

Relevant Packages: Angular 5.1.1, AngularCli 1.6.1

I have an application with a public and private side. The private side is lazy loaded after successful authentication. I have the standard core and shared modules which are used by most all modules. I also have shared feature modules that are only used by the private side of the application that is lazy loaded.

The shared feature modules inevitably make their way into the common chunk as they are referenced by other modules. The shared module also makes its way into that chunk because it is referenced everywhere. Because the common chunk contains the shared module and the shared module is referenced by the public side, it is loaded when the app first loads. So the private shared feature modules that are included in the common chunk are also loaded on first page load rather than when the the private lazy loaded feature that uses them is loaded.

#### Question

Is there a way to create multiple, minimal common chunks with the Angular CLI? At least I would like a public common chunk and a private common chunk.

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48064395/3001761

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm not seeing how that is related. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @bygrace have you found a solution to do that?

Answer (score 0):

If the shared module is referencing the private shared feature, Angular CLI wouldn't help you, however you can use dynamic import to leverage this:

```
if (shouldLoadPrivateShared === true) {
  import('/path/sharedfeature').then(sharedFeature => {
    /// use shared feature here
  });
}
```

The if condition is superfluous and is for clarity purposes BTW.

Now when the shared module is loaded the private part won't be part of the chunk since it is not hard referenced.