# Share bundle between multiple Angular apps?

Tags: angular

The closest discussion topic I've found, *[How can you share bundles in an angular 5 application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48064395/how-can-you-share-bundles-in-an-angular-5-application)*, is for Angular 5 and unresolved. Angular 6 allows multiple apps in a single project. With this, I would expect that child apps could be configured to **share build bundles such as polyfills, runtime, styles, etc.** However, this seems not to be the case.

In the angular.json file, I've tried to set the paths in the child app's `build.options` to point to the primary app's files but the issue is that the output bundles still have different hashes.

Creating a library also wouldn't work because those are for user code, not the Angular generated bundles listed above.

Is there an Angular way to do this without writing a shell script?